# How to multiply two matrices?

Tags: math, matrix

I have tried to write a function for multiplying two matrices. Matrices are represented by lists inside lists like that `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`. Although it gives result, it is not correct.

```
def Matrice_multiplicator(a, z):
    if len(a[0])==len(z):
        m=Matrice_create(len(a))
        b=0
        c=0
        k=1-1
        while b<len(a):
            for i in range(len(a[b])):
                while c<len(a[0]):
                    k+=a[b][c]*z[c][b]
                    print(k)
                    c+=1
                m[b].append(k)
            b+=1
        return m
    else:
        return "Not multiplicable"
```

Comment: A few things (there may be others): (1) take a closer look at the line `k+=a[b][c]*z[c][b]`; that's not the formula that you want. (2) when should you set `k` to zero? (3) when should you reset `c` to zero? (4) What's `Matrice_create`? See the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example: show the complete code necessary for us to reproduce. It's also helpful if you show the exact computation you did, the result that you're getting, and the result you expected to get.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix multiplication in standard Python could look like:

```py
def matrix_multiplication(A, B):
    a = len(A)
    b = len(A[0])
    c = len(B[0])
    if b != len(B):
        print (f"Wrong combination of dimensions: {a}x{b} and {len(B)}x{c}")
    else:
        return [[sum([A[i][k]*B[k][j] for k in range(b)]) 
                 for j in range(c)]
                for i in range(a)]

A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6]]
B = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8],
     [9, 10, 11, 12]]

print(matrix_multiplication(A, B))
```

Result:

```
[[38, 44, 50, 56],
 [83, 98, 113, 128]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?